# How to set a Parent Component its state from a React child Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

On a React page I have:

```
<a
    data-tab="settings"
    onClick={() =>
        this.setState({ active_tab: "settings" })
    }
>
    <i style={{ backgroundImage: "url(/icons/settings.svg)" }} />
    <span>To settings</span>
</a>
```

*How can I refactor this to a Component? How can I update the parent component (i.e., the React page) its local state from a Component?*

---

**1. With classes: based on @tom203 his answer below**

Component file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MyButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tab: props.tab,
            icon: props.icon,
            label: props.label,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={ () => this.props.updateActiveTab(this.state.tab) }
                    data-tab={ this.state.tab }
                >
                    <i style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.icon})` }} />
                    <span> { this.state.label } </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default MyButton;
```

React page (parent Component):

```
import MyButton from "../components/MyButton/";

class MyReactPage extends Component {
    updateActiveTab = value => {
        this.setState({ active_tab: value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <MyButton
                updateActiveTab={this.updateActiveTab}
                tab="settings"
                icon="/icons/settings.svg"
                label="To settings"
            />
            ...
```

---

**2. With React hooks**

Component file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MyButton = (tab, icon, label) => {
    const [active_tab, setActive_tab] = useState("data");
    return (
        <button
            data-tab={ tab }
            onClick={ () => setActive_tab({ tab }) }
        >
            <i style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${icon})` }} />
            <span> { label } </span>
        </button>
    );
};

export default MyButton;
```

On React page (parent Component):

```
import MyButton from "../components/MyButton/";

class MyReactPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            MyButton({
                tab: "settings",
                icon: "/icons/settings.svg",
                label: "To settings",
            })
            ...
```

The hook setup generates two errors:

- Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
  function component.
- 'active_tab' is declared but its value is never read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this type of states in a function. You need a React component class or use generally React [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

So replace

```
const MyButton = (props) => {
```

by

```
class MyButton extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
```

and use a

```
render() {return (<div><a onClick={this.props.updateActiveTab(tab)} ...>XXX</a></div>)}
```

Call component:

```
<MyButton updateActiveTab={this.updateActiveTab} />
```

Main class:

```
...
updateActiveTab = value => {
    this.setState({active_tab: {value}});
    }
...
```

Comment: @Marty you include the MyButton component wrong. Should be: <MyButton label={"TEST"} ... />

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my update with that. But still nothing happens when I click the link (no error in the console this time), suggesting the state of the Page doesn't change when clicking on it (which it did in the original set up where it was just on the page instead of in a Component.

Comment: @Marty could you log this.state after the button click? Check if the active_tab state was changed

Comment: I checked but the active_tab state on the page did not update/change upon clicking the button (and it did if I didn't use the component but just have the link directly on the page).

Comment: @Marty ah yeah. I see the problem. If you use this.setState in the mybutton component it will update there the "active_tab" state. It's a bit tricky to change that. But you can create a function in your main class: updateActiveTab = value => {this.setState({active_tab: {value}})}. Then pass this function to your button: <MyButton updateActiveTab={this.updateActiveTab} ... />. Now call the function in your <a>: on click={() => {this.props.updateActiveTab(tab)}}

Comment: @Marty it will take a while until I have access to my PC. It you don't want to wait so long try to understand my comment. I wrote every code you need in the comment.

Comment: Thanks @tom203, I've updated my post with my interpretation of your code. It generates the error `this.props.updateActiveTab is not a function`.

Comment: @Marty my fault. You have to create the updateActiveTab function in the main class where you call your MyButton component. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code in the OP and now get: `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render'). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Comment: @Marty remove your const in the render function const { tab, icon, label } = this.state; After that replace all vars in the MyButton component into states like: data-tab={tab} to data-tab={this.state.tab}

Comment: Sorry, it still generates the same error (updated the OP with your suggestion)

Comment: @Marty Nevertheless it should work. If you want to fix this warning you can add the following. Edit <button onClick={this.pro... to <button onClick={() => {this.props...

Comment: @Marty this.setState({active_tab: {value}}); to this.setState({active_tab: value}); And please don't ask now for every little thing. Try some things out before posting a new comment

Answer (score 0):

With Functional Components you have to use React Hooks.

Here's a link with an overview: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

In your case it looks like you just need to use the useState hook to keep track of and change your active_tab state.

Here's How I would do it:

```
import React from "react";

const MyButton = ({tab, icon, label}) => {
    
    const [tab, setTab] = useState(tab)

    return (
        <div className="tab-button">
            <a
                data-tab={tab}
                // next line doesn't work...
                onClick={() => setTab(tab)}
            >
                <i style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${icon})` }} />
                <span> {label} </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The useState calls you see return the current state and a function to change the state.

For example:

```
const [tab, setTab] = useState(tab)
```

Here tab is the current state and setTab is a function that takes an argument, in this case a tab, it would then change the current state to whatever was passed in.

Hope that helps some. Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. I've never used hooks. Your code then goes into the Component file? Or would you create a Hooks folder, just like there is a Components folder?

Comment: I get an error for `tab` in the hook: "tab has already been declared". I think it's because you have it in the parameters and as a `const`? I'm also missing `active_tab`

Comment: You have to import useState so where you import React also import useState. Like this: import React, { useState } from 'react'. This is in the same file as the component. Also change the name of "tab" in useState you can change it to const [active_tab, setActive_tab] = useState(tab)

Comment: Unfortunately, I now get the error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." I've added the hook setup to the OP.

Comment: Hey, do you have your code on github.